# Reading from check boxes doesn't work

Tags: for-loop, autoit

I want to iterate through check boxes to get the caption text from each one. I have this code but it is not working. Could someone tell me whats wrong?

Is that because later in the `For` loop I am using `$i` to iterate through other things? But it doesn't even run the `Send()` command. Does AutoIt increment the `$i` variable automatically?

```
For $i = 1 to 64
    If GUICtrlRead("$Checkbox" & $i,0) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
        Local $checkboxtext = GUICtrlRead($Checkbox[$i], 1)
        Local $checkboxtextsplit = StringSplit( $checkboxtext, "/")
        $instanz = $checkboxtextsplit[1]
        $favorite = "F" & $checkboxtextsplit[2]
        $position = $checkboxtextsplit[3]

        ;Select actual Instance from Checkbox Name.
        If $instanz = "1" Then
            WinActivate($handle1)
        Else
            WinActivate($handle2)
        EndIf

        Send("{" & $favorite & "}")
        ;...
    EndIf
Next
```

Comment: "*Does AutoIt increment the $i variable automatically?*" [Yes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/For.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was providing [`GUICtrlRead()` its parameters](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlRead.htm) the wrong way. Instead of:

```
If GUICtrlRead("$Checkbox" & $i, 0) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
    Local $checkboxtext = GUICtrlRead($Checkbox[$i], 1)
```

It should be:

```
If GUICtrlRead($Checkbox & $i, 0) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
    Local $checkboxtext = GUICtrlRead($Checkbox & $i, 1)
```

To retrieve a Checkbox checked/un-checked state use:

```
If GUICtrlRead($Checkbox & $i, 0) = $GUI_CHECKED Then ...
```

To read text of a Checkbox use:

```
$checkboxtext = GUICtrlRead($Checkbox & $i, 1)
```